# Erro ao passar parâmetro

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Vou tentar detalhar ao máximo a pergunta, mas não sei nem como exibir um erro nessa situação, se alguém puder ajudar inclusive nisso, eu agradeço.

Estou enviando dados via POST com Ajax, mas um dos campos não passa valor para o PHP.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema está no campo marca, se eu escrevo um valor direto e clico no  botão para efetuar entrada, eu recebo o valor no PHP, mas se eu executo as minhas pesquisas de marca antes, o valor não chega até o PHP. Porém a variável do JS que eu atribuo logo antes de enviar para a pagina PHP, tem valor nas duas situações.

Não gera erro no console.

Só digitei a placa, o valor vai até o PHP e volta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu defino o tipo de veiculo carro, o PHP não devolve mais a resposta, porem o alert da variável vem preenchido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
    //entrada no estacionamento
 $("#btnentrada").click(function(event){
  
  //cancelo o evento padrão do botao(submit)
  event.preventDefault();
  var cliente = $("#tipo").val();
  var txtplaca = $("#txtplaca").val();
     var cmbtipo = $('#id_tipo').val();
  var txtmarca = $("#txtmarca").val();
  alert(txtmarca);
  var cmbmodelo = $("#cmbmodelo").val();
  var cmbcor = $("#cmbcor").val();
  var cmbcobranca = $("#cmbcobranca").val();
  var txtobs = $("#txtobs").val();
  
  
  $.ajax({
   url: 'insere_entrada.php',
   method: 'post',
   data: {'cliente': cliente,'txtplaca': txtplaca , 'cmbtipo': cmbtipo , 'txtmarca': txtmarca , 'cmbmodelo' : cmbmodelo , 'cmbcor' : cmbcor , 
    'cmbcobranca' : cmbcobranca , 'txtobs' : txtobs},
   success: function(data){
    $("#resposta").html(data);
   },
   error: function(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
   },
  })
  
 });
```

```js
    //pesquisa caixa de marcas
    //tipo é o carro/ moto
 $("#txtmarca").keyup(function(){
  var id_tipo = $('#id_tipo :selected').val();
  if (id_tipo == "") {
   $("#resposta").show();

   $("#resposta").html("<div class='alert alert-warning' id='resposta' role='alert'>Preencha o tipo de Veículo<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>");
 
  } 
   //caixa é o elemento que abre com a pesquisa
   if( $(this).val() && id_tipo != "" ) {
    $("#resposta").hide();
    $("#caixa").show();
    var url = 'consulta_marca.php';
    $.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: 'post',
     data:{'txtmarca': $(this).val() , 'id_tipo': id_tipo},
     success: function(data) {
      $("#marcas_encontradas").html(data);
      //executa a funcao para que ela funcione
      PegaValor();
      
   
     },
      
     beforeSend: function(){
      $("#loader").css({display:"block"});
     },
     
     complete: function(){
      $("#loader").css({display:"none"});
      
     }
     
    });
    
   }
  
   
 });
 
 //pego a marca do carro clicada e atribuo ao txtmarca
 function PegaValor(){
  $("#mar_nome").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
      opcao = $("#mar_nome").html();
   $("#txtmarca").val(opcao);
   $("#caixa").hide();
   
  });
 }
 
 
 //pesquisa modelo quando clicar no icone de peqquisa
 $("#span_marca").click(function(){
  PreencheModelo();
  var segundos = 2; //2segundos
  
  //dar o efeito de campo atualizado para o usuario
  //escondo
  $('#cmbmodelo').hide();
  
  //mostro novamente com um pouco de atraso
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('#cmbmodelo').show();
    }, segundos*1000);
 
 });
```

**PHP**

```
//verifica se as sessions estão preenchidas
include_once("status_logado.php");
require_once('db.class.php');

$cliente= $_POST['cliente'];
$placa = $_POST['txtplaca'];
$tipo = $_POST['cmbtipo'];
$marca = $_POST['txtmarca'];
echo $marca;
die();
```

Comment: já verificou com um `console.log()` nas funções de `success` e `error` para ver se retorna algum erro?

Comment: Coloque um `.show()` na resposta do Ajax: `$("#resposta").html(data).show();`

Comment: Coloquei o .show() e funcionou! Muito obrigado! Mas porque os outros campos vem e ele não? Você consegue me passar a diferença?